# Why is request bypassing NULL check?

Tags: php

I have our users click an activation link via email when they sign up for our site.  The link looks like `http://www.site.com/?u=123&a=xyz`.

When the user hits the link, my code parses the `$_GET["u"]` and `$_GET["a"]` params.  The code makes sure there is nothing malicious and what not.  This code also checks to see if `$_GET["u"]` is set and defined.  If it's empty, it's spits out an error message.

```
if(isset($_GET["u"]) && ($_GET["u"] !== "") && is_numeric($_GET["u"]) {
     // proceed to function
     $u = clean_it($_GET["u"]);
} else {
     // show error screen
}
```

If these params ARE NOT empty, they are then sent to a function to check the values against the db.

My check, within this function, is:

```
if($u === NULL) {
     return FALSE;
} else {
     // check $u against the db
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=$u LIMIT 1;";
}
```

So when requests comes in, it's going immediately to the function and hitting the sql call.  My queries, from these requests, are looking like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=NULL LIMIT 1;
```

Why is this happening?  Any ideas?  `$_GET["u"]` is definitely being set (I can see it in the referer).  This problem does not always occur; it's pretty random.  Maybe 2-3 out of ~140 new accounts per day.

Comment: where are you assigning `$_GET['u']` to `$u`? I really hope you don't have register_globals turned on.

Comment: @sevenseacat within the // proceed to function area.  i'll edit code to reflect.

Comment: So for the second round of the quiz game that you obviously want to play: What does `clean_it` do …?

Comment: @CBroe trims, checks for malicious code... mainly uses the ADODB check.  Works fine elsewhere.  If I remove the clean_it, problem still persists.

Comment: A global, general "cleaning" function is always a ginormous red flag, because there's no such thing as generally applicable cleaning rules. What exactly is the value of `$u`? `var_dump($u)`!

Comment: @Mike are you sure that `$u` is not null because of `clean_it`?

Comment: `$u = NULL; isset($u); // returns false` so you must be setting `$u` to `NULL` in your `clean_it` function... are you sure it is returning the value instead of only changing it?

Comment: Wouldn't $u ALWAYS be null because of clean_it?  It's only happening about 2-3 times out of 140 per day.

Comment: we don't know what `clean_it` is doing, so we can't tell you...

Answer (score 0):

If it happens just sometimes, personally, I would replace those `$u === NULL` by `empty($u)`. I think you are simply trying to check that you have a value in there.

```
if(!empty($_GET['u']) && is_numeric($_GET["u"]) {
     // proceed to function
     $u = clean_it($_GET["u"]);
} else {
     // show error screen
}

if(empty($u)) {
     return FALSE;
} else {
     // check $u against the db
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=$u LIMIT 1;";
}
```

Of course since you only gave fragments of code it could be that your variable gets erased somewhere else we don't see.

On a side note - building your query like this is a bad idea. Research PHP's PDO.

Comment: `empty` treats the string '0' as no value - that's often not desirable.  (I find that I usually want to treat the empty string as equal to null, but treat the number 0 as a value - because that's what it looks like to my users.)